# Getting name of function through tryCatch block

Tags: r

I'm working on a web-scraping project that for various reasons is generating a lot of errors. I'm using tryCatch blocks to help identify and log those errors.

I would like to get the name of the function that generated the error without having to send it as a parameter in every tryCatch block.

This is a basic template:

```
a <- function(x) {
  result <- tryCatch({

    if(x != 1) 
      warning('This is not 1!')
    return(x)

  }, warning = function(cond) {
    write_issues(cond, match.call()[[1]], type = 'warning')
    return(NULL)
  }, error = function(cond) {
    write_issues(cond, match.call()[[1]], type = 'error')
    return(NA)
  })

  return(result)

}

write_issues <- function(cond, fctn, type) {
  if(type == 'warning') {
    message(paste0('Function: ', fctn))
  } else if (type == 'error') {
    message(paste0('Function: ', fctn))
  }
}

a(2)
```

I want to set `fctn` in `write_issues()` to 'a'.

With match.call by the time I get to write_issues the value of the `fctn` parameter is always something like 'value[[3]]'. I found this is because at this point it's referencing one of the handling functions (I believe).

I tried this in `write_issues()`:

```
f <- deparse(sys.calls()[[3]])
```

During testing it seemed like this would work but I'm now finding it's inconsistent.

Is this something I *have* to pass as a parameter to `write_issues()` or is there any way I can consistently grab the function I wrote that is generating the error?

Answer (score 0):

Passing an argument would probably be cleanest, but if that was not an option for some reason, you can analyze the stack trace. It is good to avoid looking at fixed offsets in the stacktrace e.g. because of possible compiler optimizations or instrumentation:

```
funname <- function() {
  foundTC <- FALSE
  for(call in rev(sys.calls()))
    if (foundTC) return(call)
    else if (identical(call[[1]], quote(tryCatch))) foundTC <- TRUE
  NULL  
}
```

This hack looks back for the first function below the first call to tryCatch. In case of instrumentation that inserted another tryCatch it will fail.